Pandas find max in previous rolling time interval
In my dataframe below, I am trying to create derived metrics from the execution_size in a rolling time interval.
I am trying to find the max value in a time window that starts at a given time before the timestamp and ends at another time also before the timestamp.
So for instance, if the start of the time interval is -1s and the end is -2s, I am trying to get, for each row, the max value of execution_size in the window from 2s before the row's timestamp up to 1s before the row's timestamp.
              timestamp     execution_size   expected_output
1    2023-10-02 07:31:42     150              NaN
2    2023-10-02 07:31:42.5   180              NaN
3    2023-10-02 07:31:43     425              150
4    2023-10-02 07:31:43.5   11               180
5    2023-10-02 07:31:44     NaN              425
6    2023-10-02 07:31:45     122              425
7    2023-10-02 07:31:45.5   NaN              11

To explain,

Row 1 and 2 don't have anything in a -1 to -2 second window before it
Row 3 has row 1 (since it's within the -1 to -2s window). Row 2, even though the execution size is greater than row 1, does not fit in that window, so is not considered.
Row 4 has row 1 and 2 in the window, so picks the greater value of row 2
Row 5 has row 1,2,3 in the window, picks row 3 as the max
Row 6 has row 3, 4, 5 in the window, picks row 3
Row 7 has row 4 and 5 in the window, picks row 4

Hope that explains things clearer
I tried using vectorised Pandas operation, which I would prefer, with something like the below, but that returns -3s to -1s.
rolling_max = df['execution'].rolling('3s').max().shift(periods=1, freq='1s')


Have you tested this approach? You can define the pre/post values the way you want, see update.

The pandas approach would be to create a custom rolling window Indexer (here PrePostWindow), that would take your -200ms/+100ms parameters:
df['max_execution_in_window'] = (df['execution_size']
                                 .rolling(PrePostWindow(df['timestamp'],
                                          pre='-200ms', post='100ms'))
                                 .max()
                                )

Full code, with that of the custom window:
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer
import numpy as np

class PrePostWindow(BaseIndexer):
    def __init__(self, index_array, pre='0', post='0'):
        super().__init__()
        self.index_array = np.asarray(index_array)
        self.pre = pd.Timedelta(pre)
        self.post = pd.Timedelta(post)

    def get_window_bounds(self,
                          num_values=0,     # not implemented
                          min_periods=None, # not implemented
                          center=None,      # not implemented
                          closed=None,      # not implemented
                          step=None,        # not implemented
                         ):
        start = np.searchsorted(self.index_array,
                                self.index_array + pd.Timedelta(self.pre))
        end = np.searchsorted(self.index_array,
                              self.index_array + pd.Timedelta(self.post),
                              side='right'
                             )
        return start, end

df['max_execution_in_window'] = df['execution_size'].rolling(PrePostWindow(df['timestamp'], pre='-200ms', post='100ms')).max()

Output:
                       timestamp  execution_size  max_execution_in_window
0  2023-10-02 07:31:42.694293342             NaN                    425.0
1  2023-10-02 07:31:42.694382842             NaN                    425.0
2  2023-10-02 07:31:42.694396562           425.0                    425.0
3  2023-10-02 07:31:42.915111402             NaN                      NaN
4  2023-10-02 07:31:43.030137780            11.0                    122.0
5  2023-10-02 07:31:43.100974920             NaN                    122.0
6  2023-10-02 07:31:43.101437340           122.0                    122.0
7  2023-10-02 07:31:43.790334200             NaN                      NaN
8  2023-10-02 07:31:44.754131658             NaN                     45.0
9  2023-10-02 07:31:44.754304038            42.0                     45.0
10 2023-10-02 07:31:44.754389398             NaN                     45.0
11 2023-10-02 07:31:44.754457458            45.0                     45.0
12 2023-10-02 07:31:44.754745838             NaN                     45.0
13 2023-10-02 07:31:44.754758978             NaN                     45.0

updated example
df['max_execution_in_window'] = (df['execution_size']
                                 .rolling(PrePostWindow(df['timestamp'],
                                          pre='-2s', post='-1s'))
                                 .max()
                                )

                timestamp  execution_size  expected_output  max_execution_in_window
0 2023-10-02 07:31:42.000           150.0              NaN                      NaN
1 2023-10-02 07:31:42.500           180.0              NaN                      NaN
2 2023-10-02 07:31:43.000           425.0            150.0                    150.0
3 2023-10-02 07:31:43.500            11.0            180.0                    180.0
4 2023-10-02 07:31:44.000             NaN            425.0                    425.0
5 2023-10-02 07:31:45.000           122.0            425.0                    425.0
6 2023-10-02 07:31:45.500             NaN             11.0                     11.0

pandas version independent signature
To generalize the above approach to previous pandas version you could set the get_window_bounds signature programmatically (those parameters are not used here, but are nevertheless mandatory):
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer
import inspect
import numpy as np

class PrePostWindow(BaseIndexer):
    def __init__(self, index_array, pre='0', post='0'):
        super().__init__()
        self.index_array = np.asarray(index_array)
        self.pre = pd.Timedelta(pre)
        self.post = pd.Timedelta(post)

    def get_window_bounds(self, **kwargs):
        start = np.searchsorted(self.index_array,
                                self.index_array + pd.Timedelta(self.pre))
        end = np.searchsorted(self.index_array,
                              self.index_array + pd.Timedelta(self.post),
                              side='right'
                             )
        return start, end
    
    get_window_bounds.__signature__ = inspect.signature(BaseIndexer.get_window_bounds)


That doesn't seem to run on my end. ValueError: PrePostWindow does not implement the correct signature for get_window_bounds

@IGottaLearnMath which pandas version did you use? This works fine on pandas 2.2.2

1.3.5 - can't update it as it's a notebook hosted on an external aws server. Thank you though, sure your answer is correct. I'll find a way around it. Marking solution as correct.

@IGottaLearnMath the exact get_window_bounds signature is not important in the computation for this custom window (we're not using the parameters). You could try to adapt it to the signature that was used in pandas 1.3.5 (see here). That should be get_window_bounds(self, num_values=0, window_size=0, min_periods=None, center=None, closed=None, win_type=None).

@IGottaLearnMath I also added an approach that should be version agnostic, although I haven't tested it on pandas 1.3.5

Perfect, thanks a lot

Code

Find the maximum value in 200ms intervals (the window with center=False). This the maximum value in the previous 200ms interval, since it is on the right)

Find the maximum value in 200ms intervals (the window with center=True). This is the maximum value in the previous 100ms to the next 100ms, since it is on the centre)

Find the maximum of those values as np.fmax.


This is the maximum value from the last 200ms to the next 100ms.
import numpy as np    
out = np.fmax(
    df['execution_size'].rolling('200ms').max(),
    df['execution_size'].rolling('200ms', center=True).max()
)

out
2023-10-02 07:31:42.694293342    425.0
2023-10-02 07:31:42.694382842    425.0
2023-10-02 07:31:42.694396562    425.0
2023-10-02 07:31:42.915111402      NaN
2023-10-02 07:31:43.030137780    122.0
2023-10-02 07:31:43.100974920    122.0
2023-10-02 07:31:43.101437340    122.0
2023-10-02 07:31:43.790334200      NaN
2023-10-02 07:31:44.754131658     45.0
2023-10-02 07:31:44.754304038     45.0
2023-10-02 07:31:44.754389398     45.0
2023-10-02 07:31:44.754457458     45.0
2023-10-02 07:31:44.754745838     45.0
2023-10-02 07:31:44.754758978     45.0
Name: execution_size, dtype: float64


Example Code of prev question
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.to_datetime(['2023-10-02 07:31:42.694293342', '2023-10-02 07:31:42.694382842', '2023-10-02 07:31:42.694396562','2023-10-02 07:31:42.915111402', '2023-10-02 07:31:43.030137780', '2023-10-02 07:31:43.100974920','2023-10-02 07:31:43.101437340', '2023-10-02 07:31:43.790334200', '2023-10-02 07:31:44.754131658','2023-10-02 07:31:44.754304038', '2023-10-02 07:31:44.754389398', '2023-10-02 07:31:44.754457458','2023-10-02 07:31:44.754745838', '2023-10-02 07:31:44.754758978'])
data = {'execution_size': [None, None, 425, None, 11, None, 122, None, None, 42, None, 45, None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)


Update answer of additional question
shift, gap = '1s', '1s' # shift is -1s(last rolling end point), gap is -2s to -1s

out = pd.concat(
    [df, df.shift(freq=shift).rename({'execution_size': 'val'}, axis=1)], axis=1
).rolling(gap, closed='both')['val'].max()[df.index]

out
timestamp
2023-10-02 07:31:42.000      NaN
2023-10-02 07:31:42.500      NaN
2023-10-02 07:31:43.000    150.0
2023-10-02 07:31:43.500    180.0
2023-10-02 07:31:44.000    425.0
2023-10-02 07:31:45.000    425.0
2023-10-02 07:31:45.500     11.0
Name: val, dtype: float64


Example Code of new question
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.to_datetime(['2023-10-02 07:31:42', '2023-10-02 07:31:42.5', '2023-10-02 07:31:43', '2023-10-02 07:31:43.5', '2023-10-02 07:31:44', '2023-10-02 07:31:45','2023-10-02 07:31:45.5'], format='mixed')
df = pd.DataFrame({'execution_size': [150, 180, 425, 11, None, 122, None]}, index=idx)


That's a nice hack, note that this is made possible due to the nature of the max function, that wouldn't be directly achievable for more complex aggregations (like mean or std)

I've added more details on the post, and simplified the examples, and explained the reason for the expected output at each row, hopefully that explains clearer

@IGottaLearnMath It looks like a very different issue has been fixed. In this case, it's better to create a new question instead of making a large edit that renders the existing answer useless. I've updated the answer anyway.

Okay I can create a new question. The initial question was the similar problem. I simplified it just by using seconds so as to make it more readable and I could provide an expected output that could be followed logically.

@IGottaLearnMath I think the question is fine, you could however clarify it. IIUC, you want to be able to use a flexible window that starts a specific time before your current time and ends a specific time after (with the possibility for those times to be negative).

@PandaKim you could update your answer to make it generic (irrespective or the passed start and end timedeltas)

I've changed the question to include a more accurate description

So how would one scale the timewindow here, say we want to look between 5 and 10 seconds, or 500ms and 1s?

@mozway I've updated the answer in response to your request. Also, as an aside, I think it's better to ask a new question when there's a major revision, but even if there isn't, it's better to leave the old question and update new question.
